# How to send data between views having a ViewScoped bean

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, parameter-passing

Background:

- I have a `ViewScoped` bean with a field named `someId`
- I have a page, `somePage.xhtml` with an `inputText` and a `commandLink`
- The value of the inputText has a corresponding field in the bean named `searchValue`
- When I click the link a method in the bean redirects to another page called `searchResult.xhtml` that use the same bean as `somePage` (although not a requirement)

Before rendering `searchResult` the bean needs to execute a search in the database, based on the value of the `inputText` and the variable `someId`. After that the result shall be shown in `searchResult`.

Is it possible to do this without:

- Using a `SessionScoped` bean, or
- Having a `h:link` instead of the `commandLink` and let `f:param`'s representing `someId` and the value of the `inputText` get updated by ajax

I've also tried `Flash`, but it seems it's not available `preRenderView`.

Comment: I'd use `#{flash}` in your case. It survives a redirect that you're most probably doing. Show your way to do the job and we'll correct your mistakes, be there any.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you navigate from the page to the searchResult.xhtml the View scoped managed bean is recreated because view scoped bean is still alive until navigation happens so your problem should solve as following:

1-create another managed bean in view scoped for the searchResult.xhtml page and define a variable someId with a set and get method

2-define an action method on your command link  (in your first bean) to save the value of someId in a flash scope then navigate to searchResult.xhtml with redirect

```
public String navigatetosearch() {
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getFlash().put("someId", someId );
    return "/pages/searchResult?faces-redirect=true";
}
```

3-in the second bean in get method restore the variable from flash:

```
public SomeId getSomeId() {
    if (SomeId == null) {
        SomeId =  getFlash().get("SomeId");
    }
    return SomeId;
}
```

and then you can use this variable in a method in PreRenderView or any place.

Comment: Seems I made an error regarding the flash; I tried to use it in an `viewParam` in page `searchResult` which didn't work. Getting it in the bean did though. Thanks